# SQL server 2017 issue with datetime datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I have a simple table which consists of 5 records with a difference of milliseconds.
I have faced issue while upgraded my database from **2016 to 2017 SQL server.** 
There are two images attached here with comparing the result of 2016 and 2017 SQL server result. I am not understanding why this unwanted behavior in 2017.

Is this a bug in 2017 SQL server. ?

Table column data type is same here in both cases **datetime** datatype.

[image: SQL server 2016 output]

[image: SQL server 2017 output]

Here is the create table query.

```
    USE [Test]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestVisionBot3](
        [FileId] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [OrgId] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [ProjectId] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
        [LockedUserid] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Here is the sample data as well.

```
    1a  1           2a  2018-04-29 10:30:30.010 test
    3a  1           2a  2018-04-29 10:30:30.553 test
    2a  1           2a  2018-04-29 10:30:30.557 test
    4a  1           2a  2018-04-29 10:30:30.560 test
    5a  1           2a  2018-04-29 10:30:30.563 test
```

Comment: If i recall correctly, the algorithm for conversions between `datetime` and `datetime2` were changed in 2016 or 2017. As your column has a datatype of `datetime` (not `datetime2`) then it is being implicitly cast to a `dateime2`. i imagine that if you cast to the correct datatype you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Larnu I think you're talking about this breaking change in SQL Server 2016 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: @MarkSinkinson that's the one! :) My Google-Fu had failed me on finding the edition. Although the OP was using 2016 in the original question, this might, instead mean that the database in 2016 wasn't in 130 compatibility, but the 2017 instance is (or 140).

Comment: Also note that `datetime` is a deprecated type and Microsoft recommends using `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` for any new development. Maybe it's time to update your schema? :)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas `datetime` isn't deprecated. Microsoft just recommend the use of `datetime2` over `datetime`. Their exact wording is: *Use the **time**, **date**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. **time**, **datetime2** and **datetimeoffset** provide more seconds precision. **datetimeoffset** provides time zone support for globally deployed applications.* [Datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql)

Comment: @Larnu I stand(sit) corrected.

Comment: @Larnu yeah, It's true After casting it to datetime it works correctly in 2017 as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Background information:**

**[Precedence rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql):**

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence.

So in your case in where clause when you compared datetime with datetime2 then datetime was bumped up to datetime2 as datetime2 has higher precedence.

Now what will that change in SQL Server 2017? In new version of SQL server, the implicit conversion will follow conversion rule from datetime to datetime2 as documented below

**[Conversion from datetime to datetime2 rule:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql)**

> When the conversion is from datetime, the date and time are copied. The fractional precision is extended to 7 digits. The following example shows the results of converting a datetime value to a datetime2 value.

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime = '2018-04-29 10:30:30.553';
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = @datetime;

SELECT @datetime2 AS '@datetime2', @datetime AS '@datetime';

--Result  
--@datetime2                  @datetime
------------------------- ---------------------------
--22018-04-29 10:30:30.5533333 2018-04-29 10:30:30.553
```

Now your earlier conversion was actually a string literal to datetime2 conversion. So it follows a different rule.

**String literal to datetime2 conversion rule:**

The string part of time is assigned to time and date to date, as is without extrapolating precision but instead right padding with 0s for extra precision.
**Incidentally this was also done for datetime to datetime2 conversion in versions before sql server 2017.**

**More explanation:**
When you convert '2018-04-29 10:30:30.553' to datetime2 to it gets to '2018-04-29 10:30:30.5530000' as it converting a string literal to datetime2

When you compare stored datetime value with datetime2 value in where clause, precedence rules apply and therefore datetime is bumped to datetime2. So when '2018-04-29 10:30:30.5530000' (a datetime value) is bumped to Datetime2 value then fractional part is enhanced and becomes greater than what was originally there.

Therefore your .553 is extended to .553333 which is greater than .533

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime = '2018-04-29 10:30:30.553';
DECLARE @strliteral varchar(max)='2018-04-29 10:30:30.553';
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = @datetime;

SELECT 
@datetime2 AS '@datetime2', 
@datetime AS '@datetime', 
cast(@strliteral as datetime2) AS strtoDatetime2,
cast(@datetime as datetime2) AS datetimetoDatetime2;

-- @datetime2                   @datetime               strtoDatetime2 
datetimetoDatetime2
-- 2018-04-29 10:30:30.5533333  2018-04-29 10:30:30.553 2018-04-29 10:30:30.5530000 2018-04-29 10:30:30.5533333
```

See image below
[image]